# how to save a sql database in a real time dataframe? shiny

Tags: r, shiny

**1. The problem:**
I am working with a sql data base, which is updated both by my shiny app and by another shiny app. I use `df=isolate(reactivePoll ())` to be able to subset the dataframe, because reactivePoll generates a **function** as a result,however `isolate()` approach has a serious problem: it only updates the dataframe when the shiny app opens, it runs only once.

How can I update the dataframe object in real time and be able to subsett it? without the error: `Error in: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` or `Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

the reactivepoll function works very well inside a render function to show tables in real time, for example, but how do I update a data.frame in real time? being able to subset it df$col1 df$col2 etc?

```r
server(input,output,session){
df=reactivePoll(intervalMillis = 2000,session, checkFunc = function(){
   
    QUERY1= "SELECT *  FROM table"
       df_rs = dbSendQuery(storiesDb,QUERY1)
    dbFetch(df_rs)}, 
    valueFunc =function (){
     
      QUERY1= "SELECT *  FROM table"
    
      df_rs = dbSendQuery(storiesDb,QUERY1)
      dbFetch(df_rs)
      
      
      } ) 
dataframe=  isolate(df()) # this approach makes the dataframe update only when the shiny app open.
}
```

**Attempts**

1-I already tried to use `dataframe=reactive({df ()})` but gives the error when i try to subset dataframe$col1: `Error in: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

2-I already tried to use `dataframe=df ()` but gives the error: `Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: The error and your code suggest that you are trying to access `df()` incorrectly. It *must* be within `reactive`, `eventReactive`, `observe`, `observeEvent`, or one of the `render*` functions. This is true of any reactive expression, not just that returned from `reactivePoll`.

Comment: For instance, this would work just fine if you did `df2 <- reactive({ head(df(), 1) })` (not that this is a meaningful thing to do).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this and gave the following error:   Warning: Error in: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  53: ifelse [# 267]
  52: server [# 267]
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: a "closure" is effectively a function, so did you accidentally do `reactive({ head(df, 1) })`?

Comment: I also put all the parts of the code that used the df() inside reactive{()} context but the problem persists: Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: no, i didn't forget ()

Comment: BTW, you're using `checkFunc` and `valueFunc` as the same thing, which is both counter to the intent (where `checkFunc` should be *fast*), and double-querying the database. (Every 2000ms, you are pulling the same data down *twice*.)

Comment: the idea of ​​the two being the same is: when there is any change in the table, send me all of it.

Comment: Yeah, I think I understand. See my answer, I suspect that `reactivePoll` is not the best function for your use-case.

Comment: Do either of the answers help, KmnsE2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're probably better off using `invalidateLater` instead of `reactivePoll`. The latter is intended to use a

> relatively cheap "check" function with a more expensive value retrieval function

In your case, you intend to run your query every 2 seconds, regardless. There is no "check" needed.

Additionally, `reactive*` functions in `shiny` tend to be *lazy* (if nothing depends on it, it will never fire), whereas `observe*` functions are more greedy (and fire regardless of dependencies).

How about this?

```r
dat <- reactiveValue(NULL)
observe({
  invalidateLater(2000)
  QUERY1 = "SELECT * FROM table"
  ret <- dbGetQuery(storiesDb, QUERY1)
  dat(ret)
})
output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
  dat()
})
```

You might want to consider only downloading *recent* data, depending on the schema of that table. For instance, if there is a timestamp (e.g., `Created` which indicates when the data was inserted into the table), then perhaps you can use something like

```r
dat <- reactiveValue(NULL)
observeEvent(invalidateLater(2000), {
  olddat <- dat()
  latest <- max(c(as.POSIXct("1900-01-01"), olddat$Created), na.rm = TRUE)
  QUERY1 = "SELECT * FROM table t where t.Created > ?"
  newdat <- dbGetQuery(storiesDb, QUERY1, params = list(latest))
  if (NROW(newdat) > 0) {
    newdat <- rbind(olddat, newdat)
    dat(newdat)
  }
})
output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
  dat()
})
```

Depending on your schema, you may also have a `Modified` field in the table, where `Created` indicates when it was first added and `Modified` indicates when it was last changed. In this case, you'll likely need to check both fields for recency. (Perhaps I'm getting ahead of myself now.)

---

*However*, you can use `reactivePoll` to do a "fast" check function and a "slower" value function, perhaps something like:

```r
df <- reactivePoll(2000, session,
  checkFunc = function() {
    dbGetQuery(storiesDb, "select count(*) as n from table")
  },
  valueFunc = function() {
    dbGetQuery(storiesDb, "select * from table")
  }  
})
output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
  df()
})
```

This idea (of using `valueFunc` for counting rows) can also be adapted to take advantage of `Created` and `Modified` ... in fact, if you have one or both of those fields, most tables will be index/optimized so that querying for the `max(Created)` is pretty fast. Granted, getting the row-count of a table is often optimized into a near-immediate query, so you might benefit from some internal benchmarking and/or a discussion with your DBA.

Answer (score 0):

`reactivePoll` returns a reactive object, so you can only access it in a reactive context. If you want to subset it, you can use the following coding style:

```
df_subset <- reactive({
  df()[, input$selected_col]
})
```

This again returns a reactive object, so you could display it with:

```
output$table <- renderTable({
  df_subset()
})
```

If you want to make changes in the database upon a change in the `df_subset`, you can use an `observeEvent`:

```
observeEvent(subset_df(), {
  # code to change the DB
})
```